# Posting data to database field, but field remains blank?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to post a value to a field in my database called 'field_from_first', with the following code:

**.m**

```
NSDictionary *reviewer = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:reviewerFirstName, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
NSDictionary *firstNameFinal = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:reviewer] forKey:@"und"];


[nodeData setObject:firstNameFinal forKey:@"field_from_first"];
```

However, the field remains blank. The console returns the structure as so:

```
"field_from_first" =     {
    und =         (
                    {
            value =                 {
                und =                     (
                                            {
                        format = "<null>";
                        "safe_value" = Brittany;
                        value = Brittany;
                    }
                );
            };
        }
    );
};
```

It looks like my value is wrapped in und twice? How can I edit my code to make sure it posts to that structure? At the moment, I believe I have it posting to: field > und > value

Comment: What is nodeData?  And what database are you talking about?

Comment: Are you using Core Data? You included the core-data tag but there's nothing in your question that indicates you're using it.

Comment: is there your fix data that means key that use that are und , value ,  und , format , safe_value ,  value ?

Comment: have you tried using main thread?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're trying to do, which is probably why you haven't received a good answer yet. If you could edit your question to describe things more fully, you might get a useful response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - ended up being quite simple. I simply needed to use the following code:

**.m**

```
NSDictionary *text = data[@"first_name"];
[nodeData setObject:text forKey:@"field_from_first"];
```

All of the other gibberish trying to post to "und" and "safe_value" was unncessary, as it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the below,

```
"field_from_first" = {
    und = (
        {
            format = "<null>";
            "safe_value" = Brittany;
            value = Brittany;
        };
    );
};
```

Your code needs to look like,

```
NSString *reviewer = @"";
NSDictionary *value1 = @{@"format" : @"<null>",@"safe_value":reviewer,@"value":reviewer};
NSArray *undArray = @[value1];
NSDictionary *firstNameFinal = @{@"und" : undArray};

[nodeData setObject:firstNameFinal forKey:@"field_from_first"];
```

Hope that is what you were asking, couldn't really tell in your question.

Comment: I want to be able to post to the field "field_from_first", not retrieve data from it. However when I use my above .m code to post to field_from_first, it leaves the field empty (thus, I'm posting to the wrong place).